# python how to change element in nested list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have been using python for a lot and today I get surprised by a simple nested list.

How can I change the value of an element of my list?

```
>>> l=[[0,0]]*10
>>> l
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> l[0]
[0, 0]
>>> l[0][0]
0
>>> l[0][0]=1 #here comes the question
>>> l
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]
>>>
```

I would expect as final result

```
l=[[1,0],[0,0],[0,0]...]
```

Why it does not append? (I would like a theoretical explanation )
How can I get the desired result?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
In starting the list in another way I get the desired result

```
>> l=[[0,0],[0,0]]
>>> l
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
>>> l[0][0]=1
>>> l
[[1, 0], [0, 0]]
>>>
```

but I am still wondering why the first version does not work and how can I initialize a  list of a lot of elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a list of the **same** `[0, 0]` element 10 times here:

```
l=[[0,0]]*10
```

Any time you modify one, it modifies them all, because *they're the same list*.

One safe way to make them unique would be:

```
l = [[0, 0] for _ in range(10)]
```

One easy way to check would be to print the `id` of each, which is the memory address where it's stored:

```
>>> for element in l:
...     print id(element)
...
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
34669128
```

Comment: Argh you beat me to it! I suppose we should find one of the thousands of dupes of this, though.

Comment: i'm practicing my speed typing. close vote has been cast

Comment: so my previous code was equal to s=[0,0] l=[s*10] and so I have always the same pointer?

Comment: @Donbeo exactly so, yes.

Comment: yes, same as `s=[0,0];l = [s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s]`

Comment: ok very well . Sometimes python can be dangerous  :)

Comment: It's a surprisingly common paradigm, stemming from how the data is stored in memory. It can be a life saver though when you *want* the feature